# update map of map in dart to firestore

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

User can save his name and photo. Users can skip to upload a profile photo. So, I already store users' data inside my DB. So, I didn't want to set null into `photo.url`. How do I create a map for this?

```
Future<void> updateUser({String name, String uid, String url}) {

        Map<String, dynamic> _map = <String, dynamic>{
          'info': {
            'name': name
          },
        };
    
        if (url != null) {
          // if user upload profile photo I want to add url to inside `info.photo`

          // got an error when try like this
          // _map['info']['photo'] = {'url': url};
    
         // this way is replace info, it's mean 'name' key is removed
         //  _map['info'] = {
         //    'photo': {'url': url}
         //  };
        }
    
        return _db.collection('users').doc(uid).set(_map, SetOptions(merge: true));
```

The final map should be like this,

```
{
'info':{
   'name':name,
   'photo':{ // if url is not null
     'url':url
   }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it easily using `if`

```
 Map<String, dynamic> _map = <String, dynamic>{
          'info': {
            'name': name,
            if (url != null) 'photo' : {'url': url}
          },
        };
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
 Map<String, dynamic> child = <String, dynamic>{'name': 'name'};
 Map<String, dynamic> _map = <String, dynamic>{"info": child};
 Map<String, dynamic> info = _map["info"];

 info.update(
   'photo',
   (value) => null,
   ifAbsent: () => {'url': 'new url'},
 );
 _map.update('info', (value) => info);
 print(_map);
```

I used a child map to enforce the type casting.

Comment: wrong bro. please check my question. I want to add `url` inside an another map(`photo`)

Comment: Yea, I saw what you did, but you get the idea. Well done.

Comment: Sorry, it' wrong.  I want to add `photo` map inside the `info` the map

Comment: your result is like this `{name: name, photo: {url: new url}}`. I want `{'info': {'name':name, 'photo':{'url':url}}`

Comment: yes. it's working. but I actual `map` is very complcated. there are so many conditions. Is there any amother way to do it?

Comment: The problem with the map is the automatic type casting that dart does. it infers the type from data contained, unless you explicitly state the type.